# how to save nssarray object into string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i want to save nssarray object into string. code is

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in blogEntries)
{ 
    NSArray *titlearray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];

    // know i want to store the object in titlearray into string how shoud i
    nsstring *STemp=? how should i write
    NSRange titleResultsRange=[sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if(titleResultsRange.length>0)
    {
        NSDictionary *titlearrayDic=[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObject:titlearray forKey:@"title"];
        [storeAll addEntriesFromDictionary:titlearrayDic];
        [listOfItems addObject:[storeAll copy]];
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you ever considered formatting your questions so that they are actually readable? There is an "Edit" button...

Comment: if you were in an interview and gave me code formatted like that, i would not hire you - surely formatting code like that makis it a nightmare to read and debug?

Comment: @Eiko and Dean

Thats not fair you have given me -1 vote. I Am new to objective c and secondly my bad english is because i am from pakistan and my Language is URDU not English. it hurts me and know i am very sad....

Comment: No downvote from me. But I *really* suggest to start from the beginning with a good book on programming, i.e. the book by Hillegass. A good understanding of the basics and foundation classes is essential, or you will run into many many problems and get frustrated soon.

Comment: ok Thanks I will study this book Promise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if understood the question correctly but in principle it should be 
possible to do like this:

```
NSMutableString sb = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSString* word in titlearray)
  [sb appendWithFormat:word];
```